# How to patch built-in/extension types in python using mockito?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

While using [mockito](http://mockito-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for unit testing in python, I came across an issue that I cannot find a solution for. I am trying to patch the usage of `io.BytesIO` in a given class method. The following code shows a simplified version where the issue occurs:

```
from mockito import mock, patch, when
from io import BytesIO

class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        # ...
        return buffer.getvalue()

def test_foo():
    bytesIO_mock = mock(strict=True)
    when(bytesIO_mock).getvalue().thenReturn('data')

    patch(BytesIO.__new__, lambda: bytesIO_mock)
    result = Foo().bar()
    assert result == 'data'
```

I am getting the following error when I execute the test:

```
/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/mockito.py:270: in patch
when2(fn, Ellipsis).thenAnswer(replacement)
/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/mockito.py:245: in when2
return invocation.StubbedInvocation(theMock, name)(*args, **kwargs)
/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/invocation.py:284: in __call__
self.mock.stub(self.method_name)
/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/mocking.py:117: in stub
self.replace_method(method_name, original_method)
/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/mocking.py:108: in replace_method
self.set_method(method_name, new_mocked_method)

self = <mockito.mocking.Mock object at 0x10d50cb38>, method_name = '__new__'
new_method = <function Mock.replace_method.<locals>.new_mocked_method at 0x10d753e18>

    def set_method(self, method_name, new_method):
>       setattr(self.mocked_obj, method_name, new_method)
E       TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type '_io.BytesIO'

/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/mocking.py:74: TypeError
```

Is there any solution to this issue, or is it just the case it is not possible to mock certain objects in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `patch` you can simply mock the response from `io.BytesIO()` as follows:

```
def test_foo():
    bytesIO_mock = mock(strict=True)

    when(bytesIO_mock).getvalue().thenReturn('data')
    when(io).BytesIO().thenReturn(bytesIO_mock)

    result = Foo().bar()
    assert result == 'data'
```

As a rule of thumb, all objects in Python can be mocked [as everything in Python is an object](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html). If you can not mock it, it is probably due to a limitation in the testing library/framework being used.